# javascript clientside routing/pathing library

Tags: javascript, routes, javascript-framework

I'm in the need for a routing library to handle my paths for a client side js app.

I'm currently using backbone.js, which while great, is not fully featured enough.

I'm looking for a dedicated pathing library that I can replace backbone with (only in terms of pathing, still want to use that for MVC), something with a lot of features.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any other frameworks other than backbone? maybe this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5112899/684890 Might be able to help?

Comment: No those are mostly mvc libs rather than routing libs

Comment: Ah I think that makes more sense now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315505/preferred-client-side-routing-solution the poster does use jQuery (you haven't specified it) but i think the answer will still relate to you: `crossroads.js`

Comment: @James I do know about crossroads, it's the first google result when looking for javascript routing library. However I'm hoping for an informed opinion and a recommendation.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't giving you an answer just suggesting that your question might be the same as the linked one and that you might find your answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of interesting routing libraries at http://www.microjs.com/#spa

Backbone, and Crossroads (and its accompanying library, Hasher) are both listed there, but you should also check out Director (independent module from the Flatiron framework) and LeviRoutes -- haven't used either but they look pretty promising.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what sort of features you are looking for, but I just put up an extremely lightweight JS router that offers the bare minimum to get things going.  A lot of the routers I had come across were offering way more features than I was looking for, so I thought this might help fill a void for those looking for something light:

https://github.com/bpeacock/lennonjs

Comment: The link is dead, could you update it pls.

Answer (score 2):

Also [Finch.js](http://stoodder.github.com/finchjs/#) seems good

Comment: Looks awesome, I would totally use this if I didn't already build a metropolis on top of backbone

Answer (score 2):

You may want to Try [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org) as well

Answer (score 1):

As the author I'm slightly biased but you could try http://davisjs.com It is a routing library that is based around pushState, although you can use hash based routing, or any thing else via extensions.

I'm not sure what features exactly that you want but Davis is full-featured, and gives you hooks into the internals so you can modify its behaviour anyway you want.