# Change browser address bar URL with jQuery & ajax without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Change browser address bar URL with jQuery without reloading
For example,

```
www.mywebsite/list.php?page=1

<a href="?page=<?php $row[id] ?>" > this link </a>
```

on click change address bar `?id=123` etc...

Comment: Change browser address bar URL with jQuery without reloading
For example, www.mywebsite/list.php?page=1

<a href"?page=<?php row[id] ?>" > this link </a>

on click change adress bar ?id=123 etc...

Comment: Changing the address bar url, client side will always reload, unless you add and anchor, as in http://www.ddfd.com#thisisananchertoaspecificplaceinthedocument.

Comment: do you mind the **appropriate answer** to be marked as **accepted **

Comment: Possible in HTML5 browsers only. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Change-Browser-URL-without-reloading-refreshing-page-using-HTML5-in-JavaScript-and-jQuery.aspx

Answer (score 5):

**not possible at all** to change the url or even query string of the browser without reloading only part you can change without refresh is #hash part of the url till html4

But in html 5 some kind of url change can be done by the new **HISTORY API** give it a try

http://html5demos.com/history

Answer (score 2):

You can not.
If you try to do it like this for example:

```
document.location.search= "?i=123"
```

It will reload the page.
What you can do is change the hash

```
document.location.hash= "#123"
```

or

```
document.location.hash= "#i=123
```

And then write a simple parsor using split to grab the data you need.
Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132848/save-xhr-rendered-state-upon-browser-refresh) you should have a look at.

Comment: Note that # (hash) params cannot be read on server side like ? (query) params - initial usage of # in urls is for "go-to anchor/id" functionality

Answer (score 2):

[`jQuery: pjax`](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) plugin may help you.